# Change permalink of hierarchical page to page id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I need to change wordpress hierarchical page permalink to the id of the page for ex if I have http://example.com/page/page1/page2 i would like to show instead http://example.com/1980 where 1980 is the id of page2 is that possible?
I used the simple usage of permalinks for wordpress and now i get for the pages http://example.com/?page_id=1980 is there any way to remove the ?page_id= and to keep just http://example.com/1980?

Comment: Do you want to do this for ALL pages on your site, or just some?

Comment: for all the pages of the site

Comment: Changing your permalink structure in WordPress admin to: "/%post_id%/" SHOULD work by all accounts, but I've just tried it on a local install and it doesn't. It loads the page, but then the URL resolves back to the post-name slug. Maybe it works for you?

Comment: No it doesnt work for pages only for posts